# Pikaday format not working

Tags: datetime, momentjs, pikaday

If I have a datetime string that come from my database e.g. 2016-02-07 00:00:00
how can I get my input field to display this using format 'DD MMM YYYY'

I have moment.js defined and the following pikday instance but the default set value doesn't display as I want it. Instead the input field displays it as `20 Jan 0000`. How can you get pikaday to display any valid datetime string in the format that you want?

```
<input id="start_dt" type="text" value="2016-02-07 00:00:00" name="start_dt">

 var start_dt = new Pikaday(
                {
                    field: $('#start_dt')[0],
                    format: "DD MMM YYYY"
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set the default value to the one that you have.
First up get the date value from the input.

```
var date = $( '#start_dt' ).val();
```

And then,

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    defaultDate : moment(date).format("DD MMM YYYYY"),
    format: 'DD MMM YYYY',
});
```